# how I can use the FFT data to compute the convolution?

Tags: fft, ifft, zero-padding

First,I have a vector `A` of length `N`,through process

```
A1 = fft(A,N);
A2 = Filter(A1);
A3 = ifft(A2,N);
```

Now,I need compute the convolution of vector `A2` with vector `B`,vector `B` is another vector with `N` elements，I noticed that seemed that I could use

```
ifft(fft(A3,2N).*fft(B,2N))
```

to calculate convolution. `fft(A3,2N)` means padding `A3` with `N` zeros.

In fact, A2 = fft(A3,N)

So, the problem is what can I do to avoid calculate A3 and fft(A3) by using A2?

Or maybe the problem is how can I use A2 to calculate fft(A3,2N)?I wan to know if I can reduce some calculations in the whole process.thanks.
Here is a matlab test

```
clear;
N = 4;
A = 1:4;
B = 3:6;
A1 = fft(A);
A2 = (A1).*2020+1234;%filter(no sense)
A3 = ifft(A2);
A4 = fft(A3,2*N);
B2 = fft(B,2*N);
x = xcorr(A3,B)%ans: 0.1952    0.4051    0.6958    1.0470    0.7676    0.5050    0.2424
x2 = ifft(A4.*conj(B2),2*N)%ans: 1.0470    0.7676    0.5050    0.2424         0    0.1952    0.4051    0.6958
x3 = ifft([A2(1:N/2) A2(N/2+1)/2 zeros(1, 2*N-length(A2)-1) A2(N/2+1)/2 A2(N/2+2:end)].*conj(B2),2*N)
%ans: 3.5624    4.2973    5.4391    6.3191    6.2232    5.2077    4.0659    3.4665
```

Comment: Please take a look on the result of `x` and `x2`. Disregarding `0` they are the same albeit with a shift.

Comment: yes,I knew about it.But my question is how can I do to make x3=x2=x1 by using The data before this line(A3 = ifft(A2, N);),like padding A2 or Insert some value.So maybe i should review the formula of FFT to find out how is each element calculated

Comment: `A5 = fft([A3 zeros(1, M-length(A3))], M);`

`x3 = fftshift(abs(ifft(A5.* conj(B2), M)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can pad zeros in frequency domain. But you need to take care about Nyquist bin when N is even.

`A3 = [A2(1:N/2) A2(N/2+1)/2 zeros(1, 2*N-length(A2)-1) A2(N/2+1)/2 A2(N/2+2:end)];`

Here Nyquist bin is `A2(N/2+1)/2` and zeros are padded in the middle of the spectrum

For N-odd

`A3 = [A2(1:(N-1)/2+1) zeros(1, 2*N-length(A2)) A2((N-1)/2+2:end)];`

**This is only for the case if you need to interpolate in time-domain. Almost irrelevant to the problem you have.**

Posted the solution to you problem below.

Comment: Your expression for A3 looks like it is missing items?

Comment: Indeed. If it is other than the square bracket then I would like to ask what else is missing in A3 of even or A3 of odd?

Comment: Also the number of zeros must be computed. I just left it there.

Comment: Include it as a complete MATLAB/octave expression and I will upvote

Comment: Included the complete expression...

Comment: What doesn't look right to me is to double count one of the bins: You have the Nyquist bin A2(N/2+1)/2 listed twice- are you sure that's right? (I guess that makes sense just "odd" )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104090/discussion-between-jomegaa-and-dan-boschen).

Comment: I corrected the mistake I made in the last line of the question(from A2 to A3),could you answer the question again?Thanks a lot

Comment: I can't get the right result,I just submitted a piece of matlab code.Maybe I misunderstood you?

Comment: no,I have already known the convolution of two signals and frequency domain multiplication of spectrum and its inverse transform match..But if i want to  calculate xcorr(A3,B) by using ifft(fft(A3,2N).*fft(B,2N)) ,I must get fft(A3,2N) first,So I need to calculate A3 = IFFT(A2,N), in other words,I I executed an IFFT on A2 with length N and then executed FFT with 2*N(padded N zeros),so i wonder if there are some formula to help me reduce these calculations

Comment: Maybe I asked an impossible question. Thank you anyway

Comment: And I noticed,A2 is the odd meelement of result of fft(A3,2N),Because I calculate fft with 2*N.Thank you anyway

Comment: @jomegaA I assume you are updating this one...

Comment: @DanBoschen Removed the miss-understood part and kept the zero-padding part as it is.

Comment: @user9568523 Hope I did not pose much of in-convenience for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
clear;

N = 4;
M = 2*N-1;

a = 1:4;
r = ones(1, N);           % Rectangular window

A1 = fft(a);
W = fft(r, N);

A2 = (A1).*W;
A3 = ifft(A2, N);

B = 3:6;
x = xcorr(A3,B)

A4 = fft(A3,M);           % A3 is interpolated by a factor of M
B2 = fft(B, M); 

Freq_Multiplication = (A4.*conj(B2));

x2 = fftshift(abs(ifft(Freq_Multiplication, M)))

% Zeropadding A2 is actually interpolation in time-domain. Not really a linear convolution. x3 will show constant results

Zero_pad_A2 = [A2(1:N/2) A2(N/2+1)/2 zeros(1, M-length(A2)-1) A2(N/2+1)/2 A2(N/2+2:end)];

A5 = fft([A3 zeros(1, M-length(A3))], M);

%x3 = ifft(Zero_pad_A2.* conj(B2), M) % This not performing linear convolution

x3 = fftshift(abs(ifft(A5.* conj(B2), M)))
```

Comment: I don't really see that you answered his question?

Comment: But I would like to know the reason why `fftshift` is requried to get the correct result.

Comment: @DanBoschen Update the code as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see how this answers the question- am I missing that? He is doing convolution with length 2N, you do 2N-1 (how come?). Also it wouldn't make sense to take the absolute value, would it? What if the result is negative?

Comment: True, but `2N` will give an extra `0` to the output sequence. With `fftshift`, `0` is at the first index of the output.


Or, are you trying to bring an idea about **circular convolution**

Comment: @DanBoschen I may want to ask at what scenarios the **circular convolution** was performed?

Comment: I was only looking to see if the answer was given to the question "So, the problem is what can I do to avoid calculate A3 and fft(A3) by using A2?" with the question being using 2N. At that point it is just math so I didn't see the answer yet. One application of circular convolution is acquisition of a repeating sequence. Anytime you are correlating or convolving with something that repeats,and you have an integer number of cycles, circular convolution is applicable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104171/discussion-between-jomegaa-and-dan-boschen).

Comment: So,you can see A5 = fft([ifft(A2, N) zeros(1, M-length(A3))], M),this line let me know A5 is just IFFT(A2) and then FFT(A2) with M size.So my question is How does A2 relate to A5 in Element level?If I set M = 2N,you can see A2 is just the odd number of A5,and what about the even part?If I can use A2 or earlier datato calculate the even part of A5 by padding A2 or by some calculation?that's my question